# Constraints in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I want to have dynamic width and height in my collectionView cells so I have only 2 cells in every screen. And 10px from top, left, right  and between them.

Example:

If I have 320px width(screen) I want 145px every cell so it would be
10px from left +145(cell) + 10px between + 145(2nd cell) + 10px from right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conform your controller to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol and implement the methods:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    let numberOfCells = 9
    let kCellHeight : CGFloat = 100
    let kLineSpacing : CGFloat = 10
    let kInset : CGFloat = 10

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return numberOfCells
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "sampleCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 2*kInset - kLineSpacing)/2, height: kCellHeight)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return kLineSpacing
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: kInset, left: kInset, bottom: kInset, right: kInset)
    }
}
```

Here is the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. this actually change something to my layout but can you update the code for vertical?

Comment: But the specifications you have specifed are according to the horizontal layout. i.e. Cell width. Tell your specifications according to the vertical layout.

Comment: I didn't understand you.. I want on every screen 2 cells and then 2 more below them and so on..

Comment: What do you mean by on every scree 2 cells? Nd what is the height of your collection view? Is it equal to the complete screen?

Comment: i mean even if i have iphone 5 or ipad i want 2 cells and below them two more depends how many i will have. Yes the height of collection view is the complete screen

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: I tested with printing the results and I see that the code is right but if the screen is more than 320px width it doesn't give the right layout.
If i try to make the width of the cell bigger than 145px from storyboard it returns it in the middle of the screen as my problem is now.

Comment: If the calculated cell width is unable to fit in the collectionView width, it is automatically sent to the next line. This is how the layout works in collection view. You don't need to specify the cell width as 145px. It is calculate on the basis of - screen size, cell spacing, left inset and right inset. For screen size more than 320 px also I am getting the same results. The only difference is that the cell width is now increased as per the screen width.

Comment: the weird thing is that it fits the screen and to be sure that its not for one or two pixels I did this: width-10 and again doesn't fit.

Comment: It might be including the cell spacing and both the insets. 1st cell will fit, but there might not be enough space left for the 2nd cell so it is moved to next line.

Comment: But it includes these that's why you subtraction them before you divide by 2

Comment: Tell me the cell width that you have used.

Comment: ok I found out what was the mistake! I tried to run it on ipad and noticed that it wasn't in full screen and i saw that I didn't have constraints for collection view...:/

Answer (score 1):

You either use stackviews or you can set width constraint of your cell and drag it into code to set the constant to half screen size.

Also why you're using constraints directly on cells when you have:

```
func collectionView(collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(width ,height);
}
```

Comment: How can I use stackviews to cells? or width constraints (all these are unable to use them). 
This function returns me an error 'CGSizeMake' is unavailable in Swift (I use swift 3)

Comment: Well the stackviews on single cell to divide it in equal views... Eg. if you have a cell which has the width of screen, you can use within it's content the stackview to divide it. But not the case. The code is written in Objective-C. The swift version is CGSize(width: X, height: Y)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code :

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (screenSize.width - 30) / 2
        let height = width * aspectRatio // aspectRatio - someValue or put height as a constant
        return CGSizeMake(width, height)
    }

this worked well for me..